# Prisma : How to query the record based on non unique columns

Tags: javascript, prisma

Prima offers quick ways to query the records in the database using API's and these functions works very well for unique columns. like I have a table membership as below

```
type Membership {
      id: ID! @id
      memberKey: String! @unique
      member: User! @relation(name: "MemberUser")
      project: Project! @relation(name: "MemberProject")
      access: [Access] @scalarList(strategy: RELATION)
      createdBy: User @relation(name: "MembershipCreator")
      updatedBy: User @relation(name: "MembershipUpdator")
      createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
      updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
}

type Project {
      id: ID! @id
      initials: String! @unique
      name: String! @unique
      desc: String
      conf: Json
      products: [Product!] @relation(name: "ProjectProducts")  
      tags: [Tag!] @relation(name: "ProjectTags")
      isActive: Boolean @default(value: true)
      createdBy: User @relation(name: "ProjectCreator")
      updatedBy: User @relation(name: "ProjectUpdator")
      createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
      updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
}
```

now If need to query the above table based on the id, I can simply do

```
 project = await prisma.query.membership({
                where: {
                    project: {
                        id: projectId
                    }
                }
            }, `{ id  }`)
```

But if I have to query on the basis of any non-unique field like Project.id I am not able to do that as Prisma by default only creates the functions for unique fields, in my case I can query on id and memberkey. the error I am seeing is

> Error: Variable "$_v0_where" got invalid value { member: { id:
>   "ck57qob5z00f90791d1973nbh" } }; Field "member" is not defined by type
>   MembershipWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean memberKey?

please help

Comment: are you sure you posted the correct error message? in your error message it states that field "member" is not defined, but it should be field "project, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `member: Member! @relation(name: "MemberProject")` or `member: [Member!]! @relation(name: "MemberProject")` to the Project type in the data model to fetch all memberships for a certain project.

Using the prisma client fluent api (not the prisma binding) it could look like this:

```
const commentsForPost = await prisma
  .post({ id: 'cjsviilj60g8y0b43bme3x8ib' })
  .comments()
```

see:

- https://www.prisma.io/docs/faq/prisma-client-vs-prisma-bindings-fq06/
- https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/

Answer (score 0):

You can only `prisma.query.membership` on `unique` fields.
To query on any field you need to use `prisma.query.memberships` with the `s` on the end.
This will return a list though, so something like:

```
const [membership] = prisma.query.memberships(...);
```

will put the first returned item into variable `membership`